# Заполнение ListView на C++

Tags: winapi, c++

Народ, кто знает, подскажите, что не так? Не заполняет ячейки, почему не могу понять.

```
BOOL My_Cls_OnInitDlgRezult(HWND hdlg, HWND hwndFocus, LPARAM lParam) {
    LVCOLUMN structColumn;
    /* создаю столбцы */
    // структура для создания строк
    LV_ITEM lvi;
    lvi.mask = LVIF_TEXT | LVIF_COLUMNS | LVIF_COLFMT;
    lvi.state = 0;
    lvi.stateMask = 0;
    lvi.iImage = 0;
    lvi.lParam = 0;
    lvi.iSubItem = 0;//№ столбца
    lvi.iItem = 0;
    lvi.pszText = "12345";
    SendMessage(GetDlgItem(hdlg, IDC_LIST1), LVM_SETITEM, 0,(LPARAM)(&lvi));
    return TRUE;
}
```

По-моему, так должно выводить в первую клетку значение 12345, но там ничего нет и нигде ничего нету. :((

Answer (score 2):

Надо бы память выделить

```
lvItem.pszText = new TCHAR[6];
strcpy(_T("12345"), lvItem.pszText);
```

а Вы ссылку копируете.