# Ошибка при работе с ListView

Tags: winapi, c++

> Сделано вопросом из комментария к ответу: [Заполнение ListView на C++](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/14253/%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-listview-%D0%BD%D0%B0-c/14275) (@ХэшКод).

Спасибо, с заполнением я разобрался, но вот вышла ошибка еще одна, с которой пока никак не справится, может знаете, как её исправить, я сделал так:

```
LVITEM item;

memset(&item, 0, sizeof(LVITEM));
item.mask = LVIF_TEXT | LVIF_COLUMNS | LVIF_COLFMT;

for (int i = 1; i< = 3; i++) {
    item.pszText = myBaseData.GetP[i];
    item.iItem = i;
    ListView_InsertItem(GetDlgItem(hdlg, IDC_LIST1), &item);
}

int BaseData::GetP(int i)
{
    return P[i];
}
```

> error C3867: 'BaseData::GetP': function call missing argument list; use '&BaseData::GetP' to create a pointer to member

Читал в инете, что надо сделать метод static, но не выходит.

Comment: @Максим Игнатьев Уважаемый участник, мы преобразовали Ваш комментарий в новый вопрос в соответствии с форматом форума.

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка говорит о том, что в вызове функции не указан список аргументов. В строчке

```
item.pszText = myBaseData.GetP[i];
```

вместо квадратных скобок надо поставить круглые:

```
item.pszText = myBaseData.GetP(i);
```

Текущий код трактуется как взятие индекса по адресу функции со всеми вытекающими.